How to write for a MG novel series?
I am writing a book series about dogs (with some wolves and other animals), with the age range being around Wings of Fire and Warrior Cats (i.e. 8-12 years). What limits would be necessary to stay within this age range?

Welcome to Writing.SE! I feel like these are two separate questions, and should be split up and asked separately. Furthermore, the first part should be answered by this question; I'm sure the second part is a duplicate as well but I haven't found it yet.

By the way, if you can't access your previous account, you can contact staff and ask for it to be merged with this one.

Actually both Wings of Fire and Warrior Cats are Middle Grade books (8-12 years). At least that is what the publisher says, e.g. here: https://shop.scholastic.com/parent-ecommerce/books/warriors-boxed-set-1-6-the-complete-first-series-the-prophecies-begin-9780062367143.html So you need to consider the limits for that age range, and not Young Adult. I have edited your question accordingly. If you actually want to write for Young Adult, please edit your question and remove the MG examples.

What do you mean with "limits"? Something like the definitions for computer games found in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PEGI for example (for Europe)? There is maybe an equivalent institution for book writing. Which one would apply is dependent on where you live at, though.

Also check this question: https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42582/crossing-the-line-from-middle-grade-to-young-adult?rq=1

After reading Wings of Fire and Warrior Cats, what can you say about the limits they seem to follow?

Could you specify by what kind of limits?
If you're talking content, you should probably stay away from:

the usual (violence, sex scenes, drug use, gore, explicit language, etc, etc)
political opinions (in my opinion)
preaching or lecturing about topics and moral lessons
lots of death (a little bit is fine)

Writing-wise, maybe avoid:

once again, lecturing or preaching
too descriptive (too many big words, too)
too metaphorical, or allegorical. Unless it's very simple, like "The Lion, the Witch, and the Wardrobe," or "Alice in Wonderland"
slow pacing
writing a boring story with too little events

